# Rename a checkbox by implementing ContextMenu c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have set of dynamically created checkboxes on a panel and also have implemented ContextMenuStrip on all checkboxes. 
I am unable to detect that which control currently displays the shortcut menu defined in the ContextMenuStrip.

Comment: Please add some code which clear ur problem. Which also show what you have tried before.

Comment: Are you really using a ContextMenu?...or a ContextMenuStrip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer.

```
private void MenuViewDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    // Try to cast the sender to a MenuItem    
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;    
    if (menuItem != null)    
    {    
        // Retrieve the ContextMenu that contains this MenuItem    
        ContextMenu menu = menuItem.GetContextMenu();    

        // Get the control that is displaying this context menu    
        Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SourceControl() property.

With a ContextMenu:

```
    private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)contextMenu1.SourceControl;
        Console.WriteLine(cb.Name);
    }
```

With a ContextMenuStrip:

```
    private void renameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl;
        Console.WriteLine(cb.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Oh!...looks like you've already found this answer on your own!  =)

Comment: yeah! Thanks fr ur answer